# How to restart a service only if the :upgrade option of the package resource is used

Tags: chef-infra

Using the **package** resource in a chef recipe, with the **:upgrade** option, I want to ensure that my sercvice is **restarted** only when it is  actually upgraded.

It does not appear this is possible. Is there a way to trigger a part of code in that event only?

```
# installs or updates package blahblah
package 'blahblah' do
  action :upgrade
end

# ensures the service is active
service 'blahblah' do
  action :start
end

# TO BE INVOKED ONLY the package is upgraded <<<============
service 'blahblah' do
  action :restart
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a notification

```
package 'foo' do
  notifies :restart, 'service[foo]'
end
```

Comment: I have 3 outcomes from the package 'blahblah':

a)  the package is not install, so it installs it
b) the package is installed and no upgrade is required
c) the package is install and an upgrade is performed

Regarding "a" it should perform a service start
Regarding "b" nothing else is needed
Regarding "c" a service restart is needed

So how to have conditional aspects such as above with the notifications you proposed?

Comment: We generally just eat the extra restart on initial install because preventing it is a lot of work for little gain.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this notifications sequence?

```
package 'blahblah' do
  action :upgrade
  notifies :restart, "service[blahblah]", :immediately
end

package 'blahblah' do
  action :install
  notifies :start, "service[blahblah]", :immediately
end

service 'blahblah' do
  action :nothing
end
```